# Accessing to a address via an int value

Tags: c, memory

Say I have a `int` value such as `10000`, I want to use this value as a memory address and access it to view it's content. I've tried the following:

```
sscanf(arguments, "%d", &address);

int * addpointer; 
addpointer = (int *) address;

printf("000%d ", address);
printf(addpointer);
```

but this throws a seg fault. What is the best way to finish this task?

Comment: You probably mean `printf("%d\n", *addpointer);`. This should do what you are asking for (i.e. a segfault).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that most people today have 32-bit ints and 64-bit pointers. Thus, casting a “plain” int to a pointer is a no-no. You may try `intptr_t` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible

```
printf(addpointer);
```

`printf()` expects it's first parameter to be a string, and you are passing an `int` pointer, which doesn't even point to a valid address.

The first argument to `printf()` is a format string so, if you want to print the value of the pointer then

```
printf("%p\n", addpointer);
```

the `printf(addpointer);` above is the cause of undefined behavior, which is why you are getting a segmentation fault.

What you are trying to do is not possible, you can't just try to inspect the contents at some arbitrary address you provide, that doesn't even make sense, because you can't be sure that there is data at that address, moreover you can't know how much data is there if there was anything.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct in that it does exactly what you said you want it do to.

Beyond that, this approach is hopelessly misguided. How on Earth can you expect a variable to contain a valid memory location that is accessible from the current process?

Please explain why you think the value put into `address` would be valid, meaningful address, and then maybe we could explain why that assumption is invalid.

If your assumption is that you can casually inspect any memory address you want, then this assumption is wrong for a couple of reasons. First, protected mode processors restrict which memory is available to your application for security reasons. Second, memory addresses are normally virtual, and so it's not even a real location in memory. Attempting to access a location that is either invalid or is protected will produce an error like the one you are seeing.

Finally, even if it was valid, the assumption that a random address points to something that can meaningfully be passed to `printf()`, which requires a valid, null-terminated string, is yet another wrong assumption.

Comment: Well, this question isn't as complicated as you might think. my program has allocate a certain amount of memories that I can see what's inside them. I have a list of them. My task is letting the user input a valid int value than convert it into the memory address and see what's in there.

Comment: @wongchito: Well obviously it's more complicated that you are thinking because the value you are accessing is causing a segment fault. I still do not understand where this address came from. Perhaps you have a good reason for not wanting to say. But it's clear to me that it doesn't point to a string that your app can legally access.

Answer (score 0):

The following program works for me. I believe it is more or less what you are trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    static int data = 42;
    static int bss;
    int *pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);

    puts("Some hints: there is");
    printf("    lib   @ %p\n", printf);
    printf("    text  @ %p\n", main);
    printf("    data  @ %p\n", &data);
    printf("    bss   @ %p\n", &bss);
    printf("    heap  @ %p\n", pointer);
    printf("    stack @ %p\n", &pointer);
    fputs("Address: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%p", &pointer) != 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("memory[%p] = %d\n", pointer, *pointer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;  /* if still alive... */
}
```

It doesn't even segfault if I stay close enough to the provided hints...

Keep in mind that, although you may be able to peek at `main()` or `printf()` on a typical PC, this is not guaranteed to work everywhere. Functions may even live in a different address space than data.